# Excel VBA macro to save a pdf to a specific file path

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to create an excel macro button that creates and saves a pdf of a range of data, macro runs on my pc with no problems.

However I need to share the excel workbook, we don’t use a network we use Dropbox so my file path saves via my user name: `“C:\Users\Username\...Dropbox`

Can I remove my name so that whoever opens the file can use the macro?

This is the code I have created so far, whilst it still works on my laptop, it doesn't work for other users:

```
Sub Create_PTC_pdf()
    Range("A76:G137").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$76:$G$137"
    ChDir "C:\Users\" & Range("F168").Text & "\Dropbox"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:= "C:\Users\" & Range("F168").Text & "\Dropbox " & Format(Date, "yyyy mm dd") & Range("O142").Text & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _ 
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

The `Range("F168").Text` references a cell that picks up the user name of whoever is in the Workbook.

Comment: perhaps `“C:\Users\" & environ("user") & "\dropbox"`

Comment: Thanks.  do I have to declare this as a string?  I tried "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Dropbox.. but to no avail.  Is it user or username?  I also tried to reference the user name in a cell:  "C:\Users\" & Range("F168").Text & "\Dropbox... but that didn't work either when I got someone else to open the workbook and run the macro

Comment: Any basic string concatenation technique will do. Use in `filename:=` parameter or assign to a string var and use that.

Comment: open a cmd prompt and type `set` then hit enter. all of your **environ**ment variables will be displayed.

Comment: It's hard to understand the context in which you are applying the dropbox path, [without seeing your code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Thank you for this, however I am a beginner at macros and not entirely sure how to do this....                                                                                                       If I pasted my macro would that help?  so you can see exactly what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sub Create_PTC_pdf()

    Range("A76:G137").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$76:$G$137"
    ChDir _
        "C:\Users\" & Range("F168").Text & "\Dropbox"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\" & Range("F168").Text & "\Dropbox " & Format(Date, "yyyy mm dd") & Range("O142").Text & ".pdf", Quality _
        :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False _
        , OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub

Comment: So for this where I specify range("F168") I have created a username in this cell so it identifies who is logged on and using the macro but it still doesn't work

Comment: @EstelleW - please don't post your code in comments - edit your question to include your code and any further clarifications.

Comment: @olly As you can see I have only joined this site today and am looking for some help, I have already edited my original question to include the code.  I am not on here to score votes or get 'likes' just asking for some help on a query

Comment: Indeed. And the guidelines are there to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Create_PTC_pdf()

    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Dropbox\"

    With ActiveSheet
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$76:$G$137"
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=sPath & Format(Date, "yyyy mm dd") & .Range("O142").Text & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With

End Sub
```